# Not able to download pdf file from Recycle Bin in MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007

I know this question is little strange but I have a sceneario where I need to download a .pdf file from a site recycle bin without restoring it to the original document Library. I am not seeing any option in MOSS 2007 to do that.

Comment: Why can't you restore it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a third party product to do this. We use Quest Recovery Manager for SharePoint which will let you restore to a different area, and preview the file before you do.